# How do you make a background image on a page scale appropriately with other page elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a webpage that looks like a legal pad paper.

I want the text on the page to stay consistent with the background image, regardless of the size of the browser.

Currently, changing the size of the browser causes disproportion on the page.

Here are two photos that show the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqqSS.jpg

How can I get around this? Thanks!

Currently, my CSS stylesheet looks like:

```
background-image: url(linktoimg);
background-position:center;
background-size:cover;
```

Comment: What is the "background" you speak of in the attached images? The scaling looks perfect to me.

Comment: Perhaps instead of using an image, you could use a table. Format the table to have the colors of a legal pad.

Then put text into each row of the table.

Comment: Since you provided no code, no one can help you.

Comment: @user3496058 I've thought of that, but I'm trying to make the page look as well designed as possible. A browser-generated table doesn't look up to par for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Leeish And would you mind telling me how sharing code that simply defines strings in JS and a background image in CSS help a potential replier answer my question? :)

Comment: @user2471760, You can use a repeated image. Make sure the image is repeatable, in that the edges of it line up. A texture. Repeat the texture as the background for each element in the table. Have the texture be something that looks relevant to the legalpad's paper or whatever part of the legal pad you're in.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of using an image, you could use a table. Format the table to have the colors of a legal pad.

Look at this jsfiddle i just whipped up to demonstrate the idea.

https://jsfiddle.net/zLmgybcv/

```
<style>
  td.legalCell{
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 25px;
    border-bottom: solid;
  }

  th.legalTop{
    background-color: brown;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 150px;

    }
  }
</style>

<table>
  <thead>
  </thead>
    <th class="legalTop"></th>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class = "legalCell">
           CONTENTS             
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! As I've said in the comments of the original post, I'm trying to go for a better look aesthetically, and a code-generated table just doesn't cut it.

Comment: You can use a repeated image. Make sure the image is repeatable, in that the edges of it line up. A texture. Repeat the texture as the background for each element in the table. Have the texture be something that looks relevant to the legalpad's paper or whatever part of the legal pad you're in.EDIT: You want to use code. Code will be the only hope of maintainability long term.

Comment: Ahh, very smart. I'll do that if there is no way to maintain the look of a full legal pad like I'm currently trying to do.

Comment: If you don't mind accepting my answer, I'd appreciate it.